# Find array elements equal to a given sum

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

Suppose array is: [1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 13, 17, 21] and you have to find 5 numbers whose sum is  equal to 31. What would be the algorithm?

Comment: Um.  Knapsack problem.  NP-complete.

Comment: Is this a question ? First mention what have you tried.

Comment: If you don't care about efficiency, maybe just brute-force it...?

Comment: NP-complete means there _is_ no efficient solution -- not really.  The best you can do is brute force.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of having nested for loops to loop through each element and add them and store the added output in a variable and check whether it equals the target sum. But obviously that is not good. So, was asking for suggestions.

Comment: It is indeed NP-complete, but that doesn't mean there is no efficient solution. The dynamic programming solution runs in O(nk), where n is the number of elements and k is the target.

Answer (score 1):

For a small array such as you have, efficiency doesn't mean much. The trick is to make it fast. Something like this would work (Written in Matlab, but it would translate to any language fairly easily):

```
array=[1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 13, 17, 21];
sum_val=31;

for a=1:(length(array)-4]
for b=(a+1):(length(array)-3)
for c=(b+1):(length(array)-2)
for d=(c+1):(length(array)-1)
for e=(d+1):(length(array)-0)
if array(a)+array(b)+array(c)+array(d)+array(e)=sum_val
fprintf("%i+%i+%i+%i+%i=%i",array(a),array(b),array(c),array(d),array(e),sum_val);
end
end
end
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pearsonartphoto, actually that small array was just to give an example.. :)

Comment: @DarkKnight: I figured as much... There's quite a bit of optimization that could be done, for instance, if you are over the sum_value, then skip to the next loop, etc. But it's a start.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto:(+1) not for the solution, but for your photographs...;)...Awesome photography..:)